# Is there a way to fix the used Run/Debug configuration in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea

I often switch between running/debugging tests locally in IntelliJ and using remote debugging my server. Therefore I have multiple run/debug configurations (the gradle ones were created automatically):

[image: Screenshot from my IntelliJ]

Whenever I execute a local test like `PdfA...en.ttete` this profile is selected by default in that combobox. But I want it to stay default on entry `Remote...Debugging 5050` so that I can easily run this profile. Is there a fix?

Other solution would be to define a Hotkey for my favourite configuration. But I couldn't find it.

Comment: don't know is that a programmer question. ask at https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/reporting-issues.html . maybe ask at https://superuser.com/

Comment: There are related requests on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-75078, https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-69968